# Should a factory always create a new object

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, factory-pattern

we have a hierarchical structure where every node is derived from a node base class `public Node(INodeFactory nodeFactory)`
The factory is injected so the node can create its child nodes using `Get(int id)`

At a later moment some nodes need a reference to another node in the structure. The information necessary to get the reference might change at runtime and is not necessarily available When the node object was constructed. Basically this method signature looks the same and is `Get(int id)`. This time no new object should be created but an existing one should be returned.

Our first attempt was to pass a `INodeLocator` that would search for the node. First of all we are not sure 'locator' is a good name and if we are missing some pattern here, maybe the repository pattern (but only to look up?). Second we noticed the method signature is the same.

We were considering to switch the factory from 'creation' to 'lookup' mode after the initial tree has been created but that won't work since later on nodes need to be created as well.

For the 'locator' logic we were thinking of searching (iterating) through the nodes but maybe it is better to keep track of them in a flat dictionary. But then the problem arises that the factory can add to the dictionary but doesn't manage the lifetime. What should happen when a node gets removed.

How can we design for this problem in a proper way?

Comment: this is not the right place for your question switch to softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: After reading https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-software-engineering I think you are probably right. I have never posted there. Should this then be deleted?

Comment: I think it should be deleted. even if it is a great question  and if you  look at softwareengineering.stackexchange.com   you don't have the close option

Comment: Who removes nodes? Nodes themselves? Some other component?

Comment: In reality this is initialized by a user action. In this simplified example you can think of it as a node that removes a node from its childnodes which causes it to be 'deleted' from the hierarchy. The deleted node can never be added again because if a node with the same contents is added it will have another unique id (Guid in reality)

Comment: @JefPatat. Questions can be moved: flag it and ask a moderator to migrate it, if that's what you want to do.

Comment: How do you determine the `id` - both when creating a new node, and when retrieving the reference to an existing node?

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @BernhardHiller I don't think that is relevant to the question. There is more logic involved in the real application. In the end the data layer is generating the new ids and the user action determines the lookup id.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate these two functions by name, and add both of them to your "factory" (which could deserve a different name). E.g.

```
public interface INodeFactory
{
    // creates a new Node and returns it
    Node Create(int id);

    // retrieves an existing node
    Node Get(int id);

    // deletes a Node
    void Delete(int id);
}
```

An implementation keeps some kind of Dictionary internally, with the id being the key, and the Node plus an indication if it was already deleted is the value.

I prefer to keep both functions in one class, as a freshly created node can be stored here and thus inconsistencies can be easily avoided.